# Tableau : Prep Builder and Tableau unable to interpret dates

Tags: csv, tableau-api

So this error makes no sense.

all of a sudden my november dates are being interpreted incorrectly, as the 11/3/2019 for example - however, the source data is stored as a number not a string so I dont understand why tableau is interpreting this data incorrectly.

The dates format in the source CVSV's has not changed either - everything is the same as it has been prior, its just an data misinterpretation that has emerged this month.

Has anyone else run into a simiilar issue? it seemse a serious error

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post any relevant information which could be used to reproduce error, below is what I have understood should solve your problem. If your year, month and day fields are separate:

```
DATEPARSE("yyyyMMdd", STR(YEAR_field)+STR(MONTH_field)+STR(DAY_field))
```

If there is single field then use the below:

```
DATEPARSE("yyyyMMdd", STR(YEAR(Field_name))+STR(MONTH(Field_name))+STR(DAY(Field_name)))
```